# I'm unable to get intel 7260 cb (IWLWIFI) to work, Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, intel, iwlwifi

I bought a new Asus Q302 with the Intel 7260 wireless in it because "hey, it is supposed to work out of the box", but it doesn't.

The computer has wifi ONLY, no ethernet jack. As such, getting wifi working isn't an option. Right now I have it online via one of those USB to ethernet adapter dongles.

I've been trolling the internet for the last three days and have followed just about every bit of advice I've found. I have reinstalled Kubuntu 14.04 (with the 3.13 kernel) three times, have downloaded the latest .ucode from the Intel site (for 3.13+ kernels) and installed it in /lib/firmware, I've tried building the firmware from kernel 3.11 as well (as seen in this [forum post on the Intel N 7260 wireless card](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2176911) ) The bluetooth, however did work out of the box, strangely enough.

My machine is up to date, I ran apt-get-update more than once.

iwconfig says:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

modinfo iwlwifi says:

```
laurence@S:~$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode                                    
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode                                    
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     5AA2E0FDE335B45C3F44AE0
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005590bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005190bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005090bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000502Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005102bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005002bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000500Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005400bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005302bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000510Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C02Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C26Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C760bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C06Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000402Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000486Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004870bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000895sv*sd00000222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00005260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004860bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000888sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000891sv*sd00004222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005207bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00004820bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C228bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001318bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001328bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001308bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001118bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001128bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001108bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Bsv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001114bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001104bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001004bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001124bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001024bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001314bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001324bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001224bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        5E:3C:0F:9C:A6:E3:65:43:53:5F:A2:BB:5B:70:9E:84:F1:6D:A7:C7
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable     agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
```

Next up, grep on iwlwifi gave me nothing

```
laurence@S:~$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
laurence@S:~$
```

Grep on "intel" says:

```
laurence@S:~$ dmesg | grep intel
[    0.650199] intel_idle: MWAIT substates: 0x11142120
[    0.650200] intel_idle: v0.4 model 0x45
[    0.650201] intel_idle: lapic_timer_reliable_states 0xffffffff
[    0.764029] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
[    0.894199] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.497821] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   10.221537] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.227958] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.342563] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
[   10.480130] intel_rapl: domain uncore energy ctr 4206:4206 not working, skip
[ 5255.145127] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 56 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 5255.145974] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 5257.167043] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
[ 5266.265207] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 5266.265521] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 5267.966360] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
[ 7142.242539] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 56 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 7142.243320] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 7144.204721] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
```

lsmod says:

```
laurence@S:~$ lsmod | grep iwl
iwlmvm                189774  0 
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwlmvm
mac80211              630653  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
```

lshw says:

```
laurence@S:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for laurence: 
   *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: e0:00:00:10:3e:a4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.1.13 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
```

I've been battling this for three days and I just can't figure it out. I've gotten wifi to work on laptops over the years, but I've finally met my match.

If you have any thoughts/ideas/anything to offer. If I can't get it working within the next day or two I'm going to have to take the machine back... which sucks because I really like it (other than the wifi).

Comment: Try and connect using KDE desktop. I've managed to connect at the campus, but not at home with KDE (didn't manage either using gnome/unity.

Comment: This issue was fixed in Ubuntu kernel 3.13.0-40 and in the 3.18 rc1 kernel.  The subsystem ID for rev cb was not in the alias list for iwlwifi

Answer (score 1):

Well, several days of this, several Kubuntu 14.04 reinstalls, a Kubuntu 13.10 install, a Linux Mint 17 install, a Debian install, upgrades to kernel 3.14 & 3.15 as well as installing the iwlwifi firmware from Kernel 3.16 did not solve anything: still no WiFi.

As such, I'm throwing in the towel and taking the laptop back. I'll buy something without a 7260 card.

A personal thanks to User310767. I appreciated your help.

Here's hoping the next laptop will be more successful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Fabby Since it was the OP that wrote this I think it is fine as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd get a different laptop anyway. I don't know if you heard but the 7260 has a tremendous amount of problems on pretty much every operating system. Windows 7, 8, 8.1, BSD, Arch, Gentoo, Ubuntu, etc. I called Intel the other day to dig deeper after my XPS 13 with a 7260 kept disconnecting. The Intel rep sounded a bit down in their response, indicating that they are working on a fix for a more stable connection, but there is no ETA. This card has been out for a year. It's not like Intel (in my experience) to not fix the issue promptly, which makes me suspect this issue dives a bit deeper into the hardware level.

For my issue in particular, my 7260 is an M.2 form factor, which I'm having a hard time finding replacements for. Dell has been great and is issuing me a replacement laptop to a system without a 7260 since, as per Dell under warranty, there is nothing else besides the 7260 in M.2 that they have available. The 7260 is also available in half sized mini PCIE form factor, which has a world of options for swapping out (unless you're unfortunate enough to have one of the laughable Lenovo or HP systems that whitelist their cards so you can't swap them. First item on the agenda when I'm president is to make this practice 100% illegal)

What concerns me most is this card is widely distributed with Dell, Lenovo, and even System 76. How on earth this makes sense is something totally beyond me, as some days I disconnect a dozen times every half hour. Others, sometimes I'll go 3 days without a disconnect, but the times it acts up makes it a definite deal breaker.

Anyway, dig around on Google with something like "7260 disconnects" if you want to read more. A lot of ticked off users out there... Sorry for my negative nanny oriented 2c on the matter, but I'd rather users be aware instead of dealing with a headache like I was.

Comment: It's no joke that this 7260 is friggin' EVERYWHERE.  80% of laptops at the store had one. I had FOUR days of headache trying to get that to work. No joke, that was the deepest I've ever delved into the guts of Linux. I learned a lot, I just wish I had something to show for ask that work. Live and learn. And thanks for your 2¢ both here and over on reddit.

Answer (score 0):

look at this bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1354975

essentially install  the Kernel 3.13.0-37_3.13.0-37.64+iwlltr0001 from: http://people.canonical.com/~sforshee/iwl-ltr/trusty/

and also install the linux-firmware 1.127.7.

If it does not work, you can try to type:

> `$echo "options iwlmvm power_scheme=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf`
>   `$echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N swcrypto=1 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`
>   `$sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

I am running an XPS-15-9530, intel wireless 9260 chip
, on kernel 3.13.0-39. 
I added the options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1, and it had no effect.
So i tried adding all your options above, and it has worked so far today.
I didn't have a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlmvm.conf, so i just created one and added your options iwlmvm power_scheme=1

from the below you can see it lists, iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode, but i can find iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode and iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode in the firmware folder /lib/firmware   so i was curious can I/should I make it use the ...-9.ucode version? how do i tell it to use the latest one rather than ...-7.ucode?

my resulting modinfo looks like:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     C2D0F3DFCA289585C100E36
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005490bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005290bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005590bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005190bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005090bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000502Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00009200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00009010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005102bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005002bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005200bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000500Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00001010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005400bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005510bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005410bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005012bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005210bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005302bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Bsv*sd00005310bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd0000510Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005112bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00005010bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00008270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00008070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B4sv*sd00000270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000172bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B3sv*sd00000070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C02Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C26Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000C270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C760bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C770bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C06Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000C070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004420bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000402Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00005070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004360bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004370bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004560bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004570bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A6Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004A70bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000486Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004870bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004472bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004470bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004272bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B2sv*sd00004270bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004162bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004160bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004170bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004072bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00004070bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000893sv*sd00000262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000892sv*sd00000062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000895sv*sd00000222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000894sv*sd00000022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00005260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004860bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000446Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004460bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd0000426Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd0000406Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Esv*sd00004060bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004462bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000888sv*sd00004262bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000887sv*sd00004062bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004822bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004422bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000891sv*sd00004222bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000890sv*sd00004022bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00005015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00005005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001017bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AFsv*sd00001015bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001007bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000008AEsv*sd00001005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000084sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000083sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000886sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000885sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000089sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000087sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005207bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000091sv*sd00005201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000090sv*sd00005211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005317bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Bsv*sd00005315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005327bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000008Asv*sd00005305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00004820bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C228bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd0000C220bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd0000C020bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001318bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000085sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001328bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001308bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000082sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004239sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001118bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004238sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001307bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001128bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001108bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000422Bsv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Dsv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Csv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Bsv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000423Asv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001114bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001014bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001111bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004236sv*sd00001011bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001104bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001004bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001101bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001124bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001024bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001121bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004235sv*sd00001021bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001316bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001216bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001315bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001215bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001314bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001311bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004237sv*sd00001211bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001326bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001226bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001325bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001225bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001324bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001224bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001321bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001221bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001206bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001305bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001205bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001304bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001204bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001301bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00004232sv*sd00001201bc*sc*i*
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E3:C1:65:D0:89:1E:3C:EE:B6:DD:5C:18:C7:E1:99:3C:D2:49:56:B0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
➜  ~  modinfo iwlmvm 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     D8BB21196A865641A4A81D0
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        E3:C1:65:D0:89:1E:3C:EE:B6:DD:5C:18:C7:E1:99:3C:D2:49:56:B0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
```

Answer (score -1):

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

Download the 7260 one, unzip and move to firmware folder.

Comment: I just noticed you said this didn't work.. try upgrading the kernel to 3.15 and doing this again. I have a laptop with the same 7260 running manjaro with 3.15. Works flawlessly, I used to use 14.04 but I ran into the same issue and the firmware always fixed it but after a certain update, didn't work till I upgraded to the 3.15 kernel for some odd reason. OR Could be a faulty wireless card is all.

Comment: I can confirm that the card is in good order, the machine came with Windows 8.1 and it worked just fine in that OS. I'm currently dual-booting the machine.

I'll try the 3.15 update. I really hope that works, I want this "adventure" to be over

Comment: Well, Kernel 3.15 didn't do anything at all.

I'm going to try another idea, will report back.

Answer (score -1):

I have an asus q302. What I did to get my internet working is I deleted the iwlwifi-7 driver. Moved the -8 driver to /lib/firmware. Updated my kernel to 3.16 and rebooted. Worked fine so far.

Comment: This is a public Question&Answer site, which has the aim to transparently help many visitors with the results of the posts in here. This is why we don't have a PM (private message) function and instead show all conversations to the public. So please discuss any problems here on this site either using comments on a post or in the public viewable chat rooms and do NOT invite people to an email discussion about questions posted here. Btw are you sure that you want you email address to be published here and readable to everybody?

Comment: Can you describe in detail how you did that? Even I as an experienced Linux user have problems following you.